# How to continue code execution if JavaScript geolocation pup-up is not answered by user?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, geolocation

We have a webpage that asks the user's geolocation at signup.

The webpage uses `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( ... )`.

However, we observed that on some computers (Windows 10 with Chrome or Edge) the pop-up requesting the user to "Allow" or "Deny" the location request is not shown. We also found out that if the user resizes or moves the browser window, the pop-up appears, and it can be answered.
However, if the pop-up is not answered, the code remains stuck at waiting for user action. I'd like to know if there is a way to just continue code execution if the user is not answering at a certain time. It would be like a pop-up timeout. After the timeout, I can just simply assume the user denied the location request. In any case, we have to make our website continue code execution even if the pop-up is never answered.

`getCurrentPosition(success callback, errorCallback, {timeout: 5000})` is not working in this case. That timeout refers to the case when the user allows geolocation, but the process times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
// this flag is to only call errorCallback if getCurrentPosition never calls the callback functions
var geolocationRequestCompleted = false;

getCurrentPosition(succesCallback, errorCallback, {timeout: 5000})

setTimeout(function () {
    if (!geolocationRequestCompleted) {
        errorCallback()
    }
}, 5001)
```

this way, after 5001 ms if a callback (success or error) has not been called, you will force errorCallback() and the app can proceed. The flag `geolocationRequestCompleted` needs to be set to true if errorCallback or successCallback gets called so that after 5001 ms, the timeout doesn't call it a 2nd time.

Comment: It would be good to include a link to [*getCurrentPosition* at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition). ;-) And the OP already covered the *timeout* option (it doesn't close the dialog or unblock the UI).

Comment: consider using [watchPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) with its clear option [clearWatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/clearWatch)

Comment: Fayzaan This seems to be interesting solution. I will try it and accept your answer if it is working.
@Yaelet I don't see how watchPosition can be beneficiary for a signup page. A user usually signs up a single time. And, I don't see how watchPosition is relevant to my question.

Comment: @PatkosCsaba my intention was to be sure that the request is canceled, while still achieving getting the position data. You can clear the request immediately after you get the position data you need, as well as cancel it with the suggested timer. In this case above, you are still at "risk" of the successCallback firing because the user may still grant you access. That's might introduce some very strange non-deterministic results because you both failed and succeeded.

Comment: @Yaelet

I agree that there may be a situation where a user may accept after the timeouts defined above. A better solution to something like this is to create this feature as a service, and not hold back the application from doing its initialization. This way your application is not stuck while waiting for a response from the user.